# what are the available devices for 1x,2x and 3x

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, screen-resolution, uiimageasset

I was trying to find list of iPhone & iPad devices by screen resolution 1x,2x and 3x.

Searching the stack overflow doesn't give any clue on following things
is there any need to support 3x images for iPad because no iPad seem to support 3x and Other iPad2 is there any other ipad or ipad mini that still supports 1x.

is there any iPhone device that still supports 1x.

I couldn't find any answer for this questions.

Baasically if we have the list of devices for both iPhone and iPad by screen resolutions 1x,2x and 3x it'd be easy to test.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

Comment: Thanks it doesn't show 1x device of iPhone and 1x,3x device of iPad an d no information about it.I would like to know that so that I can do the testing

Comment: Here you have to do the math, but you should be fine: http://iosres.com

Answer (score 4):

**1× Devices**

iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS

**2x Devices**

iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 5c, SE, 6, 6s, 7, 8

**3x Devices**

iPhone 6+, 6s+, 7+, 8+, X

Comment: Can you please add like this for tablet as well ?